# how to write an fscanf argument that properly stores values and works with varying matrix sizes?

Tags: c, file, variables, matrix, dynamic

i have a 15 x 5 grid of ones and zeros in a file. how do i store them in a t[15][5] block?
the first line of the file is the dimensions of the matrix, then starting from the next one its the grid. ive only started learning C recently and im struggling with it right now.

additional question, how do i write a one-size-fits-all code that correctly stores any size matrix if its provided in the first line of the file? lets say the file this time says 20 3 in the first line, so i should make t[20][3]. is it possible without scanning each line as a string and then chopping it up?

Comment: First read the matrix size, then allocate memory for the matrix, then a double loop to read in the matrix data, one element at a time. Don't call it `t` but something like, well `matrix`.

Comment: 1.) If you post exact file contents you may get more exact answers.  I recommend that edit, and 2.) show code you have so far, and 3.) post just one question per post in stack overflow.

Comment: "is it possible without scanning each line as a string and then chopping it up?" --> Yes it is possible.  There is little wrong with "scanning each line as a string and then chopping it up" as that is the best generic approach with good error checking.